# Where are predatory publishers based?

Tags: reference-request, disreputable-publishers

Is there any research/study/survey that looked at the location of predatory publishers? (e.g., x% are based in country A, y% are based in country B, etc.)

I am mostly interested in English-speaking venues and the field of computer science. Trends over time are welcome as well.

Comment: (+1) for the question, as Beale's list is not there now. Sad! If you remove the constraint "English-speaking venues", then it would be India? However, Indian do use English as primary language now-a-days.

Comment: Given that many predatory publishers apparently consist of one person and some cloud-hosted websites, how would you define where they are "based"?  The country where the person lives?  The country where their bank account is set up?  The country where the web server is located?

Comment: @NateEldredge The study should indeed ideally clarify its definition of "based".

Comment: And how do you count? Some will be publishing 100s of 'international journals', will you only count them once? Or by spam email volume?

Comment: @coder there are archived versions.

Comment: What about those that use a front in say India or China, but the money actually flows to the U.S.?

Answer (score 6):

There is a [study by Shen and Björk (2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s12916-015-0469-2) which includes a figure (Fig. 6) showing

> the distribution of the publishers across geographic regions. The distribution is highly skewed, with 27 % publishing in India.

---

Figure 6:

[image]

(the figure's license: Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/), which permits unrestricted use, distribution, and reproduction in any medium, provided you give appropriate credit to the original author(s) and the source, provide a link to the Creative Commons license, and indicate if changes were made)